# Hiding <p> field in javascript

Tags: javascript, api, function, hide, reddit

Here's my code for gathering titles/posts from reddit's api:

```
    $.getJSON("http://www.reddit.com/search.json?q=" + query + "&sort=" + val + "&t=" + time, function (data) {
    var i = 0
    $.each(data.data.children, function (i, item) {
        var title = item.data.title
        var url = item.data.url
        var id = item.data.id
        var subid = item.data.subreddit_id
        var selftext = item.data.selftext
        var selftextpost = '<p id="post' + i + '">' + selftext + '</p><br>'
        var post = '<div>' + '<a href="' + url + '">' + title + '</a>' + '</div>'
        results.append(post)
        results.append(selftextpost)
        i++
    });
});
```

Basically every post (selftext) is assigned a different paragraph id (post0, post1, post2, etc) for every result that's pulled. I'm also going to create a "hide" button that follows the same id scheme based on my i variable (submit0, submit1, submit2, etc). I want to write a function so that based on which button they click, it will hide the corresponding paragraph. I've tried doing an if statement that's like if("#hide" + i) is clicked, then hide the corresponding paragraph, but obviously that + i doesn't work. How else can I tackle this?

Comment: you can use a self-executing function that closures a given i value, avoiding to have it modified for your click handler purposes

Comment: So do you mean like, when I add the code to create each hide button, I have add the function within the onclick of the button to hide that corresponding post?

Answer (score 1):

Could you try something like the below?

```
showhide = $("<a class='hider'>Show/Hide</a>");
results.append(showhide);
$(showhide).click(function() {
    $(this).next().toggle();
}
```

Alternatively:

```
$.each(data.data.children, function (i, item) {
    var title = item.data.title
    var url = item.data.url
    var id = item.data.id
    var subid = item.data.subreddit_id
    var selftext = item.data.selftext
    var selftextpost = '<p id="post' + i + '">' + selftext + '</p><br>'
    var showhide = $("<a class='hider" + i + "'>Show/Hide</a>");
    var post = '<div>' + '<a href="' + url + '">' + title + '</a>' + '</div>'

    results.append(post)
    results.append(selftextpost)
    results.append(showhide);


    $(showhide).click(function() {
        $(this).next().toggle();
    });

    i++
});
```

Comment: Hmmm, that's giving me a "Shell form does not validate error".
I put the code between results.append(post) and results.append(selftextpost)

Comment: This is probably a dumb question, but do I have to make another function called toggle() that shows/hides the p? or is toggle() a built in function that already does that?

Comment: I'm assuming from the $ in your code that you're using jQuery so should have "toggle" available as a function which should show hide. I've updated the code a bit.

Comment: Yep, I'm using jQuery. I tried your alternate code, which makes more sense to me, but I'm still getting that "Shell form does not validate" error.

Comment: Okay I figured that out, just needed to add the ); at the end of the } bracket. Now the Show/Hide isn't showing up as a link, only text?

Comment: Can you go into Firebug console and copy the html nodes that you're playing with into your example above? It would help me understand the hierarchy.

Comment: Here's my fiddle with everything: http://jsfiddle.net/elliotmersch/BmL4M/21/
Thanks for the help!

Comment: I've updated the code above. Based on how your code was rendering I've used $(this).next().toggle() which grabs the element immediately below the anchor and hides/shows it - hope this helps.